# Menu list item width refuses to change?

Tags: html, css, menu, height, width

my css code is...

```
.list {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#menucontainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 1001px;
}
#menu {
    position: relative;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    width: 91px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #12aeef; 
    color: #ffffff;
}
#menu ul li ul { 
    display: none; 
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#doubleline {
    line-height: 20px;
}
#regularline {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

and my html for the menu is...

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href=""><b>Home</b></a></li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>HTML</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
                    <li id="doubleline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Making an HTML File</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hello World</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Body</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Font</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>DIV</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tables</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Links</a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#">Images</b></a></li>
                    <li id="doubleline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Bold, Ittalics, and Underline</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Positioning</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tips and Extras</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>PHP</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Making a PHP file</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hello World</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Echoing</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Variables</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>If Statements</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Functions</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Forms</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>MySQL</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tips and Extras</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Java</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Using Java</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hello World</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Variables</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Functions</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Alerts</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Getting Elements</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Mouse Events</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tips and Extras</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>JQuery</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Using JQuery</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hello World</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Variables</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Functions</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Alerts</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Getting Elements</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Mouse Events</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tips and Extras</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>CSS</b></a>
                <ul id="regularline" >
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Introduction</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Making a CSS File</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hello World</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Classes</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><font size="2"><b>Getting Elements</b></font></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Hover</b></a></li>
                    <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Tips and Extras</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="../code_editor/"><b>Code Editor</b></a></li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="sign_in/"><b>Sign In</b></a></li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="register/"><b>Register</b></a></li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Forums</b></a></li>
            <li id="regularline" ><a href="#"><b>Contact Us</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now for some reason I cant change the second layer's width.

```
#menu ul li:hover ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

is where it should be changing. As a test I have set it to 100px instead of the 91 on the parents. the height changes just fine but the width refuses. help please i'm stumped./b

Comment: please, give a better indentation. Thank you.

Comment: And please use jsfiddle.net to show us the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MDUhS/ simple copy paste but whatever.

Comment: How can you not understand the problem? I said specifically what the problem is. The second layer of the menu ( what appears when you hover on the parent) will not change width. It stays the width of its parent. that bottom piece of code should specify the width for the second layer but it wont change, the height parameter works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix your problem `#menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}` you need to specify the a on the sub ul li. I hope this helps.

EDIT: you will also need to add a width to the ul li ul like this `#menu ul li:hover ul {
    width: 200px;
}`

Comment: That helped but check out the improved jsfiddle...it only expands a few pixels?

Comment: is there a link to the new jsfiddle?

Comment: I've created a quick jsfiddle based on your code http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/ugqu9/ I have tidied up the HTML and CSS to keep everyone happy. You needed to define a width for the ul li ul also. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: Did it work? I've edited my answer above. It it does the job don't forget to give it an up vote. Cheers.